# Find the inverse of the function

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function, inverse

Find the inverse of the function $f(x) = -2 \cdot4^{2(x-3)} - 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Try to express $x$ with $y$ and you find

$$y=f(x)=-2\cdot4^{2(x-3)}-1\iff x=\frac12\log_4\left(-\frac{y+1}2\right)+3$$

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of a function is found by substituting y for x and vice versa. So, we alter our equation to look like this:

$x = -2 * 4^{2(y-3)} - 1$

and solve for y.

$x + 1 = -2 * 4^{2(y-3)}$

$\frac{x + 1}{-2} = 4^{2(y-3)}$

$log_{4}(\frac{x + 1}{-2}) = 2(y-3)$

$\frac{log_{4}(\frac{x + 1}{-2})}{2} = y - 3$

$y = \frac{log_{4}(\frac{x + 1}{-2})}{2} + 3$

Therefore, $f(x)^{-1} = \frac{log_{4}(\frac{x + 1}{-2})}{2} + 3$

Comment: ugh, Latex makes that inner part a bit hard to read; it's `x+1/-2` inside the brackets

Comment: Hi Devon, is it generally true that $log(-×) = -log (x)$ ? If yes, what would be a small (algebraic) proof to convince myself?

Comment: @user139167, oops, it's not. I made a mistake there D: and I am editing my answer now.